# Decreasing resolution of screenshots increases file size

Tags: preview, graphics, screen-capture, image-editing

I've noticed that on my rMBP, when I try to make a screenshot smaller using Preview.app version 6.0.1 (Tools -> Adjust Size).

When I'm trying to decrease the image size to upload it, the file size often increases.

Compare these two files:

- [The first one](http://abload.de/img/winter-nature-wallpapg2kzg.png) is 3.3MB. Resizing it to 70% of the resolution results in a file size of 2.1MB.
- [The second one](http://abload.de/img/wp-screenshotcbk3d.png) is actually a screenshot of the first image. It's 4.5MB, but again resizing it to 70% results in a file size of 5.2MB. Resizing it to only 99% results in nearly double of the size (8.6MB).

How can this happen? What is going on here?

Comment: Are you resampling the image when you change it's size within preview?

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean? The only thing I do is open the Adjust Size dialog, change the metric to percent, adjust the size and confirm it, and save the file.